# Java fatal error file showing insufficient memory while heap dump is much smaller

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am running a Java based application and it is crashing due to Insufficient memory. Some output snippet of hs_err :

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 24696061952 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error 
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_275-b01) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

But when I am taking heap dump it shows memory around 8GB. My jvm arguments are : -Xmx30720m -Xms30720m -Xmn7168m -Xss8m

top command shows

```
 PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 20   0 82.7g  36g  33m S 10.6 61.9  63594:19 java
```

/proc/meminfo

```
/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       61833192 kB
MemFree:         2235872 kB
MemAvailable:   20808016 kB
Buffers:          213036 kB
Cached:         17876428 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         55994452 kB
Inactive:        1816412 kB
Active(anon):   39721444 kB
Inactive(anon):      132 kB
Active(file):   16273008 kB
Inactive(file):  1816280 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:              1312 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      39721564 kB
Mapped:           107292 kB
Shmem:               140 kB
Slab:            1280320 kB
SReclaimable:    1121808 kB
SUnreclaim:       158512 kB
KernelStack:       67824 kB
PageTables:       103072 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    30916596 kB
Committed_AS:   75073316 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       12288 kB
DirectMap2M:    62902272 kB
```

I don't understand how to debug here as nothing shows up in heap dump, the heap dump is smaller compared to a heap dump of healthy running application. Any idea how to identify which part of program is holding up memory?

Comment: This is not a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.  The JVM itself tried to allocate 24GB.  How much memory does your system have? How loaded is it?

Comment: I used Mat to check if there is any leak, I use a Guava cache which is top in dominator tree but even for that its retained heap size is 3.2G.

Comment: Added meminfo, total memory is 62G.

Comment: I don't understand what is keeping all that memory if heap dump shows memory occupied like 8GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used -Xms to force the JVM to get ~30GB at JVM startup.

It has tried, and failed. It only obtained 8GB. It needs another 22-ish GB but cannot get it. That is what the error message is telling you.  This is consistent with a dump that says the heap is only 8GB.

You're asking for more than the OS will provide. You'll need to figure out what's going on in the OS in general.

Your application code is probably not involved. The JVM is still initializing its heap in accordance with your command-line options.

Comment: Thanks, this explains why JVM is crashing. Is there any way I can tell why JVM is not able to procure that additional space? To answer that I might have to see where that space is being used. Actually top command is confusing as it says RES is 36G so I thought java process have already got the memory it needed. Any recommendation how to debug further?

Comment: I assume "something else" is holding on to it.  Could there be a previous instance of your application stuck somewhere, somehow?

Comment: @leo017 “so I thought java process have already got the memory”… well, the JVM thought the same, otherwise it didn’t start (due to the `-Xms` option). The problem is, simply said, the operating system told the JVM that it has the memory, but when the JVM tried to actually use it, the os that “whoopsie, don’t have the memory”. Note the phrase “for committing reserved memory” in the error dump. It was reserved, but different operating systems have different ideas of the bindingness of a reservation.

Comment: @Holger that makes sense. This was something I was wondering too, and your answer clarified that. I further kept looking and used pmap command but seems the application is holding up all the memory and all those big blocks of memory are listed as "anon". I hit the wall there, and gave up further debugging as even heap dump didn't show anytime. Killed the process, started it again and it was successful.